# PHP Session won't keep array variables

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

I have an **Index** page with login form, a verification page called **Login** and **content**.

**Index** is fairly simple: if logged in, redirect to **Content**, otherwise display login form and POST to **Login** page

index.php:

```
 <?php    
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['usr']) && isset($_SESSION['pswd'])){
        header('Location: content.php');
    } else {
?>    
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title> PHP Login </title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <center>
                    <form method="POST" action="login.php">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Username:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="usr"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Password:</td>
                                <td><input type="password" name="pswd"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>
                                <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </center>
            </body>
        </html>
<?php } ?>
```

Then we have **Login** verification: compare the POST vars with coded variables, if all is good, set Session variables and redirect to **content**.

login.php:

```
<?php
session_start();    
if($_POST['usr']=='user' && $_POST['pswd']=='password'){
    $_SESSION['usr'] = 'user';
    $_SESSION['pswd'] = 'password';
    header('Location: content.php');
} else {
    echo "post: ";
    print_r ($_POST);
    //header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

Then we have the **Content** page, check that the Session is set and display content, otherwise PRINT_R

content.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['usr']) || !isset($_SESSION['pswd'])){
    // header('Location: index.php');
    echo "session: ";
    print_r ($_SESSION);
} else {
    include 'logoff.html';
?>
    You are logged in!!!
<?php } ?>
```

The process works, up to the Content page. I keep getting a blank SESSION array, and when I try going to Index, it pretends I never logged in. what am I missing?!

**Edit:** in The code above, content.php is trying to check if the session is set. If it is NOT set it will show me a blank array (for debugging purposes, but normally I want it to go back to index, since the user is not properly connected),

if it IS set, it will echo "you are logged in". It is also including a page called 'logoff.html' as that page has a button to destroy the session.

Even without the IF statement, simply running a  `print_r ($_SESSION);` returns a blank array. This means there is no problem in the IF statement, but something that happens before it.

**Solution**: I didn't know about this before, but some hosting sites require some PHP set up, before they can store PHP sessions. I went to the knowledge base of my hosting service and searched for "session", and found an explanation on how to set up the **php.ini** file to save my sessions in the correct path.

Comment: Hey @toms, sorry that your crippling issue (which I have dealt with myself many times when setting up servers...) has been met with such incompetence... Usually StackOverflow is better than this, but... -sigh-

Comment: Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol I hope my edit made it easier for everyone to understand it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure sessions are configured properly. For example, is the session save handler set correctly? If using files, does it have permission to access the specified folder? If memcache, is that set up properly?

This would be the main reason for session variables to not be saved.

Comment: Thanks for your persistance in the comment sections above. You are the only one who gets the code. How do I check those configurations?

Comment: I found it!! I had to find and edit my **php.ini** on the hosting server and change the file path to the **/cgi-bin/tmp/** directory, as explained in the knowledge base of my web-hosting service.

Comment: -nods- Thank you for paying attention, a lot of people would have just ignored my answer because it has a negative score. I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue!

Answer (score -3):

```
change this 

    <?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usr']) || !isset($_SESSION['pswd'])){
     // header('Location: index.php');
     echo "session: ";
     print_r ($_SESSION);
    } else {
     include 'logoff.html';
    ?>
    You are logged in!!!


    <?php } ?>




  i think in your code when session not set then it will print so change it with



    <?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['usr']) && isset($_SESSION['pswd']))
    {
      // session is set
     // header('Location: index.php');
     echo "session: ";
     print_r ($_SESSION);
    }
    else 
    {
       /// session is not set
     include 'logoff.html';
    ?>
    You are logged in!!!


    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: For f---'s sake... THE "YOU ARE LOGGED IN!" IS ***CLEARLY*** IN THE `ELSE` BLOCK!

Comment: if(isset($_SESSION['usr'] , $_SESSION['pswd']))
{
     // header('Location: index.php');
     echo "session: ";
     print_r ($_SESSION);
  
  // login 
} 
else
{
 // session not set 
  include 'logoff.html';
}

Comment: login is inside the if condition

Comment: The commented "// header('Location: index.php');" is fairly obvious proof that the `print $_SESSION` is only there for debugging, and that normally the user would be kicked back to the front page... *because they aren't logged in*. `logoff.html` almost certainly contains a "Log out" *link* that is reused in several places - why else would you include an HTML file???

Comment: ***You do not address the problem...***